# Android studio 3.0 (Beta) не видит R

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, gradle

Решил поставить Android Studio 3.0 beta 2.

Раньше использовал 2.3.3. Я удалил Android Studio 2.3.3 и SDK (вместе со скрытыми папками и кэшем).

После установки создал проект:

- MinSDK = 17 (Android 4.2)
- TargetSDK = 26 (Android 8.0)
- buildTools 26.0.1

Почти сразу появились 2 ошибки:

Во первых Android Studio не видит класс **R**. Скриншот:
[image: Ошибка: не удалось найти класс R]

Во вторых Gradle не может собрать проект из-за ошибки в **~/.gradle/caches/.../values/values.xml** Скриншот:
[image: Ошибка с values.xml]

Лог Gradle (очень длинный): https://gist.github.com/sashaqwert/4a7967a719280d005c4e215f089640a1

**Clean project** не помогает.

P.S  Обновил Android Studio до **beta 3**. Осталась та же ошибка.

Comment: Я помню эту студию 3 canary, там была ошибка invalid dimen, вроде бы решалось установкой "." в качестве разделителя. Но появились новые ошибки и я ушел обратно на 2.3 версию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android Studio 3.0** Beta, как и canary не компилирует проекты из-за ошибки **invalid dimen**, которая приводит к тому, что не видно класса **R**.

Для решения проблемы нужно запускать файл studio.sh в кодировке **EN_US UTF-8**.

Самое простое решение - это создать вспомогательный **.sh** файл в катологе с **studio.sh**.

В него записать:

```
env LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" ./studio.sh
```

Для запуска Android studio использовать, созданный вами, файл.